# Passport sign in with Google: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: node.js, express, authentication, passport.js

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?response_type=code&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A6046%2Fauthorize&scope=profile&client_id=723881342981-bmaun4etu8cdoeocbne2k4vss4kutqhr.apps.googleusercontent.com' (redirected from 'http://localhost:6046/login/') from origin 'http://localhost:5173' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

```
import express from "express";
import dotenv from "dotenv";
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import cors from "cors";
import passport from "passport";
import GoogleStrategy from "passport-google-oauth2";
import { User } from "./models/User.js";

dotenv.config({ path: "./config.env" });
const app = express();

app.use(express.json());
app.use(
  cors({
    origin: ["http://localhost:5173"],
    credentials: true,
  })
);

passport.use(
  new GoogleStrategy(
    {
      clientID: process.env["GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID"],
      clientSecret: process.env["GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET"],
      callbackURL: "/authorize",
      scope: ["profile"],
    },
    async function verify(issuer, profile, cb) {
      /* find if user exists if not create one if it does */
      console.log(profile, "--what profile looks like");
      /*
      const User = await User.findById(profile.id);

      if ( User ) {

      } else {

      }
      
      */
    }
  )
);

//DATABASE CONNECTION
const DB = process.env.DATABASE_STRING.replace(
  "<password>",
  process.env.DATABASE_PASSWORD
);

mongoose
  .connect(DB)
  .then(() => {
    console.log(`Database Connection was Successfull !`);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error, "error happened ---");
  });

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  console.log(`req recieved`);
  res.status(200).json({ message: "hello!" });
});

app.get("/login", passport.authenticate("google", { scope: ["profile"] }));

app.get(
  "/authorize",
  passport.authenticate("google", { failureRedirect: "/" }),
  (req, res) => {
    // Successful authentication, redirect to a success route or send a response
    res.redirect("/protectedResource");
  }
);

app.get("/protectedResource", (req, res) => {
  res
    .status(200)
    .json({ message: "you have been granted access to view the resource" });
});

app.listen(6046, () => {
  console.log(`server running on port 6046`);
});
```